# How can I encode a real-time video from dynamically spaced frames?

Tags: delphi, ffmpeg

I'm trying to create a video from a series of screenshots. The screenshots are in a database and have dynamic FPS (1-3 FPS). How can I create a video file with constant FPS?

Before performing `av_packet_rescale_ts` I tried to change the `st^.codec.time_base.den` value on the fly between 1 and 3.

This is the basic cycle of encoding of one picture:

```
repeat
  fillchar(pkt, sizeof(TAVPacket), #0);
  av_init_packet(@pkt);

  (* encode the image *)
  ret := avcodec_encode_video2(st^.codec, @pkt, frame, got_packet);
  if (ret < 0) then
  begin
    writeln(format('Error encoding video frame: %s', [av_err2str(ret)]));
    exit;
  end;

  if (got_packet > 0) then
  begin
    (* rescale output packet timestamp values from codec to stream timebase *)
    av_packet_rescale_ts(@pkt, st^.codec.time_base, st^.time_base);
    pkt.stream_index := st^.index;

    log_packet(oc, @pkt);
    (* Write the compressed frame to the media file. *)
    av_interleaved_write_frame(oc, @pkt);
  end;
  inc(frame.pts);

until (av_compare_ts(frame.pts, st^.codec^.time_base, 1, av_make_q(1, 1)) >= 0);
```

Changing the FPS on the fly causes the video output to fail. If I don't change the `st^.codec.time_base.den` value the video speeds up and slows down.

Comment: What do you mean by "*screenshots are in a database and have dynamic FPS*"? The fps is a property of the stream that the frame belongs to, and not a property of the frame itself. Frames have timestamps and/or durations. You need to keep timebase fixed and assign accurate timestamp or duration to ensure playback represents realtime.

Comment: Identical frames compress well so might be easiest to start with 6 or 12 frames per second encoding and duplicate the frames going in.  (ex for 12fps, duplicate the 1,2  and 3 frames per second 12, 6 and 4 times each). Also see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68770/converting-png-frames-to-video-at-1-fps

Comment: @Gyan:
screenshots are written to the database with their timestamps, the recording frequency can be 1 screen or 2 screens or 3 screens per second

Comment: @Brian:
thanks, thought understood, I need to determine the maximum FPS and duplicate the missing frames

Answer (score 0):

There is no notion in ffmpeg of a dynamic timebase, so changing it during encoding is forbidden.  But you are free to set the PTS of your frames before encoding to anything monotonically increasing.

You are not showing how you set the PTS in your example code.  If you want a constant framerate, just ignore the timestamps from your database, count the frames and calculate a PTS according to the frame number (probably this is what ffmpeg is doing when you don't give it any PTS).

If your frames were recorded with a varying framerate, but you didn't record any timestamps for them, you cannot get a smooth looking video anymore.

Comment: this function is set PTS: av_packet_rescale_ts,
I set only FPS: st^.codec.time_base.den (before encoding)

Comment: [av_packet_rescale_ts](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.1/group__lavc__packet.html#gae5c86e4d93f6e7aa62ef2c60763ea67e) converts existing PTS/DTS from one timebase to another, but it can't do anything if there is no timestamp set in the first place.

Comment: after performing this function (av_packet_rescale_ts), the pkt.pts and pkt.dts and pkt.duration are set

Comment: this from examples:
https://github.com/DelphiForBroadcasting/ffmpeg-delphi/blob/master/Examples/ffmpeg-examples/%2Bmuxing/Project1.dpr